# Nice Initialization of thread with pure virtual function

Tags: c++, multithreading, virtual

Here I was designing snall Pipe class hierarchy, problem is, I want to make the hierarchy minimal to the final user , so the only thing he has to do is to overwrite the virtual 
    function like this :

```
template <typename T> class Processable{

protected:

public:
    std::thread  processLoop;
    void myWrapper(Processable<T>* pp ){    pp->processLoopFunction();};
    virtual void processLoopFunction() = 0 ;
    Processable(   ):processLoop(&Processable<T>::myWrapper,this,this){ processLoop.detach();};
    ~Processable(  ){};

};


template <typename T>  class Source ;

template <typename T> class Sink : public virtual Processable<T>{


    // virtual void processChunk(void) = 0;
    // virtual void isChunkReady(void) = 0; 
protected:

public:
    Source<T>* mySource;
    Sink():mySource(nullptr){};


};

template <typename T> class Source : public  virtual Processable<T>{

protected:


public:
    lockfreequeue<T>  myOutputDataBuffer;


    void setSink(Sink<T>&);
    virtual void processLoopFunction() = 0 ;
};

template <typename T> class Pipe : public virtual Source<T>, public  virtual Sink<T>{

public:
    virtual void processLoopFunction() = 0 ;

};


template <typename T> Pipe<T>& operator|(Source<T>& lhs, Pipe<T>& rhs  ){ lhs.setSink(rhs) ;return rhs;};

template <typename T> Sink<T>& operator|(Source<T>& lhs, Sink<T>& rhs  ){ lhs.setSink(rhs) ;return rhs;};


template <typename T> class PipeDouble: public Pipe<T>{

public:
    virtual void processLoopFunction()  ;

};    

template <typename T> class OutputSink : public Sink<T>{
public:

    virtual void processLoopFunction() ;

};


template <typename T> void Source<T>::setSink(Sink<T>& pp){        
    pp.mySource = this ;
};      


template <typename T> class FileSource : public Source<T>{
    std::ifstream myInputFile;
public:
    FileSource(string filename):myInputFile(filename){};
    virtual void processLoopFunction()  ;
};

template <typename T> class NumberSource : public  Source<T>{

public:
    NumberSource(){};
    virtual void processLoopFunction() ;           
};        

template <typename T> void OutputSink<T>::processLoopFunction(){   
    T tmp;
    while(true){
    if(this->mySource!=nullptr){
        this->mySource->myOutputDataBuffer.pop(tmp);
        cout << tmp << endl;
    }
    }

}

template <typename T> void FileSource<T>::processLoopFunction(){

    T ll = 0;    

    while(myInputFile >> ll){
    this->myOutputDataBuffer.push(ll);
    }
}

template <typename T> void NumberSource<T>::processLoopFunction(){

    T ll = 0 ; 

    while(true){
    this->myOutputDataBuffer.push(ll);
    ll++;
    ll++;

    }
}    

template <typename T> void PipeDouble<T>::processLoopFunction(){
    T tmp;

    while(true){
        if(this->mySource!=nullptr){
            this->mySource->myOutputDataBuffer.pop(tmp);
            tmp  = tmp + tmp;
            this->myOutputDataBuffer.push(tmp);
        }
    }    
}
```

Of course I end up with

> tom@oberon:~/CPP/Pipes> ./a.out  pure virtual method called terminate
>   called without an active exception Aborted

But not always ( for some derived classes it throws that error , for some others don't ) ;
Is there some nice way of doing it , besides initializing std::thread  processLoop; in every derived class separatly ?

Comment: I know why this happens , I want to know how to ommit that gracefully .

Comment: The only way I know of (if you want to stick with running the thread's code in a virtual method) is to have the constructor not start the thread -- instead, have a separate `Start()` method that the user needs to call after constructing the `Processable` object, and a `Stop()` method that the user is required to call before destroying the `Processable` object.  Of course that introduces its own issues (such as the user potentially forgetting to call one or both of those methods at the appropriate times), but you can partially address those problems with RAII and/or run-time assertion-failures.

Comment: Possibly of interest:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151787/is-there-any-automated-way-to-implement-post-constructor-and-pre-destructor-virt

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inheritance.

```
template<typename T, typename Engine>
struct Processable {
  Engine e;
  std::thread myThread;

  Processable( Processable&& ) = default;
  Processable( Processable & ) = delete;
  Processable( Processable const& ) = delete;
  Processable( Processable const&& ) = delete;
  Processable() = delete;
  Processable& operator=(Processable const&) = delete;
  Processable& operator=(Processable &&) = delete;


  template<typename... Args>
  explicit Processable(Args&& args):
    e( std::forward<Args>(args) ),
    myThread( &Engine::processLoopFunction, &e, &e )
  {
    myThread.detach();
  }
};
```

Now clients create an Engine type with a (non-virtual) `processLoopFunction`, then you instantiate a `Procesable<T, Engine>`, which automatically does the post-construct work for it.  It also perfect forwards the Engine's constructors.

But really, creating a **class** to do this seems pointless, when all you want is an invokable object.  Why not just take an arbitrary type and invoke `()` on it instead of a named `processLoopFunction` method?

Similarly, creating thread objects and detaching them is rarely a good idea, as you just made clean shutdown basically impossible.

Comment: Well, I wanted to have nice class hierarchy would indicate which of the class is reading from the input or write to the output or both ( abstract : class Sink , class Source , class Pipe ) I paste more of my class hierarchy.