# How to avoid two step initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'd like to follow the RAII(resource acquisition is initialization) idiom throughout my code but I'm also doing the template method pattern where I'm developing generic versions of my classes and using them to build a common codebase for certain things. Sometimes I need to enforce an initialization sequence where I would need to call the specialized object's virtual functions in the constructor but that's not possible in C++. The only solution I can think of is a two step initialization by calling an init function after the object is created but that breaks the RAII idiom. Is there any solution to this?

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        // I want to call B's foo() here
    }
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {}
    virtual void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a(static_cast<A*>(new B));

    // Use b polymorphically from here...
}
```

Edit: seems my example was too simplified, here is another one that might better illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        foo();
    }
    void init()
    {
        // bar() must be executed every time A is created but the derived classes will decide how to implement it
        bar();
    };
    void foo() { std::cout << "Part 1 of algo\n";  };
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {}
    virtual void bar() { std::cout << "Part 2 of algo\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a(static_cast<A*>(new B));
    a->init(); // I don't want to have to call this every time I instanciate it
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `B`'s `foo` in the constructor of `A`? Why can't `B`'s constructor call it, in which case it will work properly?

Comment: This doesn't work like you might think it works, because you need a B object to call B::foo(), and you don't have a B object until `B::B()` starts running. And that only happens after `A::A` returns.

Comment: @Brain Because I want to upcast B to A and use A, I want to enforce all Derived of A to call foo() in the construction

Comment: @MSalters I know, I'm trying to find a way around this

Comment: If `B` needs a certain invariant to hold for its `A` subobject, then I still don't see why `B` can't simply call `foo` on the first line of its constructor body. Can you give a more detailed example of what you're trying to enforce and why it has to be done this way? That may help us suggest a solution.

Comment: @Brain I don't know if I can explain it better than in my OP but this is in the context of the template method pattern where A implements a certain behavior that needs to be done for all of the classes that will derive from it, all derived classes need foo() to be called during construction but they will use their own implementation

Comment: Your example just looks like regular inheritance. Can you add the template pattern usage to it that best resembles what your code actually looks like?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151787/is-there-any-automated-way-to-implement-post-constructor-and-pre-destructor-virt

Comment: You current approach is not possible. You are trying to call B from A when B hasn't been completely constructed. In addition it looks like A is used as interface class. Why you are using inheritance is not entirely clear. Have you considered using a template class instead of inheritance? If you insist on using inheritance, this is generally achieved by making the constructor private and providing a create function (search for the factory/builder design pattern)

Comment: You *can't* call any `B` methods from the constructor of `A` without getting undefined behavior, it's simply impossible by the rules of the language. The best you can hope for is to have `B`'s constructor call a method of `A`. P.S. you've simplified your example too much, nobody's able to say anything constructive. If you fleshed it out a bit we might be able to come at your problem from a different angle.

Comment: Voting to close as lacking relevant example.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why must `main` call `init` instead of the `B` constructor calling `bar`?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<A> a(static_cast<A*>(new B));` this cast is completely unnecessary (also you'll hit undefined behaviour because you don't have a virtual destructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, using a static factory function to create B (and can potentially be any kind of derived class through the use of templates) which calls onNew() after construction. The only way to create B is by calling the create function which instanciates B and returns a shared pointer, this shared pointer has a custom deleter which calls the "destroy" function automatically. This allows for post-construction and pre-destruction work to be done (could be modified for other types of pointers too).

For those still confused as why I'm doing this, it's because:

- I can enforce an initialization and destruction sequence in A by calling functions in onNew() and onDelete() (like foo() and bar())
- Those functions have to be called in the order I want to, but they have to be defined by the derived classes
- This leaves little room for error for creators of the derived classes because they have a very strict implementation to follow
- It also leaves no room for error in the usage of the classes because the user does not have to manually call onNew() and onDelete(), it's all done automatically.
- I can upcast to A and and use it polymorphically with better confidence that it's in a valid state and has been properly initialized, no further checks are necessary after the object is created.
- In onNew(), I could also return a value from foo() and set it as a member variable and operate on it in other functions. In those functions I wouldn't need to check that those member variables are properly set because it's enforced in the post-construction.

-

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A 
{
protected:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}

    virtual void onNew() 
    {
        foo();
    }

    virtual void onDelete() 
    {
        bar();
    }

    void destroy() 
    {
        onDelete();
        delete this;
    }

public:
    template <class T> static shared_ptr<T> create() 
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "T must be a descendant of A");
        shared_ptr<T> t(new T(), [](T *p) { p->destroy(); });
        t->onNew();
        return t;
    }

    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class B : public A 
{
    friend A;

protected:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}

public:
    virtual void foo() override 
    {
        cout << "B foo";
    }

    virtual void bar() override
    {
        cout << "B bar";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    shared_ptr<A> a = static_cast<shared_ptr<A>>(A::create<B>());
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I also want the objects to be plain fields in a struct. Can't use the factory for that :(

Answer (score 1):

Do not use virtual dispatch for this.

```
A(std::function<void(A*)> foo)
{
    foo(this);
}
```

or

```
A(std::function<void()> foo)
{
    foo();
}
```

Now child types of `A` pass the body of `foo` to the `A` ctor.  Of course this `foo` better not rely on having a valid `B` or even `A`.

You could restrict construction to a private/protected pathway and require phased init in its final pseudo-constructor.  Maybe have a CRTP helper that descendants are supposed to use to implement the phasing (DRY).

But this requirement is a red flag that your types may be full of spaghetti logic.  Sometimes required, but often avoidable.

Another completely different approach is to throw away the paticular C++ built-in OO system if it does not match your needs.  There are myriads of ways to implement OO; assuming the built-in C++ way works best for your problem is the hammer-nail solution (you got a hammer, so that problem looks like a nail).

For example, if you regularize the type and place the inheritance as an implementation detail, or write your own vtables, the "problem" of two-phase init can go away (as these wrap init in another layer of abstraction).

Learning how idiomatic OO "works" in Smalltalk, Perl, C, Python, C#/COM/.net, MFC, Objective-C, Haskell, Javascript, and Lua (as a set of examples off the top of my head) should each give you a different way to approach a "manual" OO solution (with some overlap).

Comment: a `function<void(A*)>` can't be called without arguments.