# OOP design: force calling virtual members from constructor

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a problem in a library I am developing. The problem is that, for what I designed, I need to call a pure virtual function from the constructor. But I need to avoid undefined behavior.

This is the design I have a class `shape` that needs to be used as a sort of interface:

```
class shape
{
public:

    shape(std::shared_ptr<configuration> conf)
    { generate(); }

    std::shared_ptr<generated> mesh;

protected:

    virtual void generate() = 0;
};
```

The user, as far as I have designed, will write a class that will actually create the mesh. My idea, right now not working, is to force calling the `generate` method **without the user's intervention**.

In other words, the construction of the derived class **must** create the mesh. If I leave it to the user, the explicit call to `generate` could be forgotten and will result in some weird and destructive behavior that won't be noticed until really later (this should **never happen** for this library). I was thinking also of using CRTP or something from TMP but I cannot devise anything that is similar in simplicity to the above code.

Note that this **is not a runtime requirement**, but a compile-time one.

How can I design the base class and eliminate the possibility of forgetting one call?

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: Why is `generate` not simply the constructor of the derived class?

Comment: How can I be sure the user implemented a generation that will yield a non null pointer?

Comment: Just receive it as a parameter and assert that it is non-null. The derived class can use a function to create it if it wishes so.

Comment: This is possible but changes entirely the semantics, there is no constraint this way on the user's class, and `generate` is superfluous: the user can even just write a function, and I would not have a class `triangle` derived from `domain`.

Comment: Well, your constraint is just "give me a mesh". That's covered by a constructor parameter: you can't even begin constructing a `shape` without a valid mesh. What's that about `domain`?

Comment: Every shape must have a mesh provided so it makes sense to me that the mesh would be a base class constructor parameter. Then each different shape provides a different mesh and is free to create it as it pleases.

Comment: Can't you [delegate to another class](https://wandbox.org/permlink/a6lrXFjgUKtpHAGW)?

Comment: Possibly of interest:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151787/is-there-any-automated-way-to-implement-post-constructor-and-pre-destructor-virt

Comment: There is a FAQ entry on the isocpp site that addresses just this problem https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctor-idiom

Comment: @skypjack you were probably right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could fake it with on-demand/lazy construction:

```
class shape
{
public:
    shape(std::shared_ptr<configuration> conf) {}

    std::shared_ptr<generated> get_mesh()
    {
       if (mesh == nullptr) mesh = create_mesh();
       return mesh;
    }

protected:
    // Should be implemented to create and return the appropriate mesh object
    virtual std::shared_ptr<generated> create_mesh()() = 0;

private:  
    // don't access this directly, always call get_mesh() instead!
    std::shared_ptr<generated> mesh;  
};
```

The mesh won't be created until the first time someone calls get_mesh(), but as far as the outside world is concerned, the mesh will always be available when it is needed.  (Note that this presumes that your shape class's own constructor doesn't need access to the mesh object; if it does, then John Zwinck's suggestion is probably your only option)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the constructor to take a mesh as an argument.  The derived class will then have to create it.  The construct may as well be protected too.

Comment: I would like to be able to have various subclasses as triangle, square, and yet retain some properties in the base class, for instance, the mesh size.

Comment: That's fine.  Just do what I said and use the mesh you get in the base constructor to assign the base member variables.