# Automatically Call Method After Final Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have written up a framework for threaded objects with the following very basic structure:

```
class ThreadedObject {
public:
    ThreadedObject(Thread* parentThread);

protected:
    virtual void initialize();
}

class MyThreadedObject {
public:
    MyThreadedObject(Thread* parentThread) : ThreadedObject(parentThread) {}

protected:
    void initialize() override;
}
```

I have a mechanism whereby I don't call methods of subclasses of ThreadedObject's directly, instead I pass them onto a queue (via std::function) to be executed within the correct thread (parentThread).

I ran into an issue with the initialize method.  The intent of this method is to act as a thread-conscious "constructor."  What I mean is, since a ThreadedObject can be created in ANY thread, that means its constructor will run in the thread is was created in.  However, I want the initialization (that would normally be in the constructor) to occur within the parent thread of the ThreadedObject instance.

The simplest solution to this problem would be:

```
Thread myThread();
MyThreadedObject myObject(&myThread);

invoke(&myObject, &MyThreadedObject::initialize);
```

Assuming the invoke method looks at what thread is assigned to myObject and queues a call to initialize within that thread.

However, I am wondering if there is any way to have this happen automatically AFTER the object has been constructed.  My naive solution was to do the following:

```
ThreadedObject::ThreadedObject(Thread* parentThread) {
    //...
    invoke(this, &ThreadedObject::initialize);
}
```

However, I learned quickly that you can't call a virtual method like this from within the constructor of a base class.

It looks to me as if I need some way to call initialize AFTER all the layers of constructors (base -> child 1 -> child 2 -> ...) have completed.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I found an article about the same problem here: [Is there any automated way to implement post-constructor and pre-destructor virtual method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151787/is-there-any-automated-way-to-implement-post-constructor-and-pre-destructor-virt)

I am wondering if my real question then becomes, is there a way to wrap the construction of ThreadedObjects and their child classes in some sort of critical section so that construction completes before any other threads can take over?

Comment: I hate to digress, but have you considered just constructing `ThreadObject`s on the thread on which they'll live? `Thread` could provide a templated function to construct anything and either return a future, or else just synchronise with its thread before returning. Sorry not to be able to answer the actual question put.

Comment: @Tommy After much thought, I decided that your solution is actually the best.  It requires me to change quite a bit of code, but, the result is much cleaner than the alternative.