# Cleanup resources of base class before destructing derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

I implemented an own Runnable to call threads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

class Runnable {
public:
    Runnable(): running_thread_(nullptr) {}

    void run() {
        if(running_thread_)
            return;

        running_thread_ = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(&Runnable::run_thread, this));

    }

    virtual ~Runnable() {
        stop();
    }

    void stop() {
        if (running_thread_ && running_thread_->joinable()) {
            running_thread_->join();
        }
        running_thread_ = nullptr;
    }

protected:
    void run_thread()
    {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
        start();
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual bool start() = 0;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> running_thread_;
};

class TestRunner : public Runnable {
public:
    virtual ~TestRunner() {
    };

protected:
    bool start() override {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto testRunner = std::make_shared<TestRunner>();
    testRunner->run();
}
```

If I run the code I get following output:

```
/home/vagrant/tmp/clionTestProject/cmake-build-debug/clionTestProject 
a 
pure virtual method called 
terminate called without an active exception

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

It seems that start() is called after the destructor of TestRunner. The call of stop() on the destructor of Runnable() does not help as the destructor of TestRunner is executed before. At least I found that I can repair it by calling stop in the destructor of TestRunner:

```
    virtual ~TestRunner() {
        stop();
    };
```

Using this destructor everything works as expected. But I would not like to care in the derived classes about calling the stop() methods, all the thread handling shall be covered in Runnable. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

**So, what I am searching:** Is there any way to prevent from Runnable that the destructor of TestRunner is called before the thread is done?

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to write a Java-esque interface of some sort. I honestly don't think it's a style that translates well to C++. I'd try to learn the C++ idioms if I was in your shoes. For instance, a `std::unique_ptr<std::thread>` is an exercise in redundancy here. A `std::thread` is already a move only type that can be "empty". The indirection via pointer serves nothing. This too strongly suggests trying to do Java in C++.

Comment: Possibly, invert dependency: `template <typename T> /*requires (T t) { t.start(); }*/class Runnable : public T {/*..*/};`. `virtual` should be dropped.

Comment: [Can reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef8f7597a0e73d6f)

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. `TestRunner` is destroyed _before_ we wait on the thread :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative could be to not let `TestRunner` inherit from `Runnable` but to let `Runnable` have a `TestRunner` member variable. This avoids the problem completely.

I've removed the smart pointers here because I think they are only taking focus from the real problem that the derived class object may get destroyed under the feet of the thread. That is, before the `virtual` member functions gets called and also while the thread is running and working on member variables in the derived class.

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// A base class for TestRunner
class RunnerBase {
public:
    void stop() { terminate_ = true; }
    bool terminated() const { return terminate_; }

    virtual void operator()() = 0;

private:
    std::atomic<bool> terminate_ = false;
};
```

The `Runnable` constructor now forwards its arguments to the member variable (which is of type `TestRunner` in our case).

```
template<class T>
class Runnable final {
public:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<RunnerBase, T>, "T must inherit from RunnerBase");

    template<class... Args>     // constructor forwarding to the runner
    Runnable(Args&&... args) : runner{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

    void run() {
        if(running_thread_.joinable()) return;
        running_thread_ = std::thread(&Runnable::run_thread, this);
    }

    ~Runnable() { stop(); }

    void stop() {        
        if (running_thread_.joinable()) {
            runner.stop();
            running_thread_.join();
        }
    }

protected:
    void run_thread() {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
        runner();
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::thread running_thread_;
    T runner;
};
```

`TestRunner` inherits from `RunnerBase` and can check `terminated()` if it's time to terminate.

```
#include <vector>

class TestRunner : public RunnerBase {
public:
    TestRunner(size_t data_size) : foo(data_size) {}

    void operator()() override {
        while(!terminated()) {
            // work on data that only exists in the derived class:
            for(auto& v : foo) ++v;            
            std::cout << '.';
        }
    }

private:    
    // Some data that the thread works on that wóuld get destroyed before
    // the base class destructor could call stop() if inheriting `Runnable`
    std::vector<int> foo; 
};
```

The creation is just slightly different.

```
int main() {
    Runnable<TestRunner> testRunner(1024U);
    testRunner.run();
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a cool solution. I will give it a try.

Comment: @SaschaEffert Hope it helps. Your question made me rethink som old desigs of mine.

Answer (score 1):

One method piggy-backs on your use of `std::shared_ptr<TestRunner>`. I don't like it very much, but it works (until you decide to get rid of the shared pointer).

```
class Runnable : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Runnable>{
  ...
      running_thread_ = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(&Runnable::run_thread, shared_from_this()));
  ...
  static void run_thread(std::shared_ptr<Runnable> s)
  {
      std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
      s->start();
      std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
  }
  ...
```

This guarantees that your Runnable object won't be destroyed while `run_thread` is executing.

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about such a solution, but it will fail as soon as I create a TestRunner on the stack or as uinque_ptr... In fact I nearly never use my Runnables with shared_ptrs, because the owner is quite clear...

Comment: An object can delay its own destruction by waiting in the destructor. If you don't want that, you need something external to the object. `shared_ptr` does that by preventing the destructor from being called. You can also wait before the destructor in something that is external to your object. Overall there is not a good design. Just ditch the inheritance. Composition works better every time.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. His code already attempt to wait in the constructor, but for some reason that isn't working.... Oh I see the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `main()` method returns (and therefore your `TestRunner` object gets deleted) before `run_thread()` can execute in the other thread.  Therefore, when `run_thread()` *does* get executed in the other thread, it's being called on an object that has already been partially destroyed (i.e. `~TestRunner()` has already been called by the main thread), invoking Undefined Behavior so bad things happen.

If you add `testRunner->stop()` to the end of `main()`, you can avoid the problem, because that ensures that `main()` will not return (and therefore the `TestRunner` object will not be destroyed) until *after* the spawned thread has exited.

It would be nice to be able to rely on the `stop()` call in `~Runnable()` to handle it for you automagically, but by the time `~Runnable()` executes, it's already too late, your object's subclass-layers have already been destroyed, and your thread is already trying to use a broken object.

Comment: I understand the problem. Calling the stop method in main is at the end same as adding this to the constructor: The user of Runnable has to care about ensuring that destruction is not dome too early. I am searching for a way to come arround this requirement...

Comment: Yeah, me too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151787/is-there-any-automated-way-to-implement-post-constructor-and-pre-destructor-virt

Comment: Btw the difference between calling stop() in main() vs in ~TestRunner() is that if you call it from main(), then when someone subclasses TestRunner() it won’t reintroduce the problem at the sub-sub-class level.